# asp.net: output object properties to html

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know of a class or something that will display an object as HTML, so i can view al the properties and values of that object, and go deeper inside them?

Idealy i would like to get a web-page that looks like the popup-windows that you get in Visual Studio when you click an object while debugging. So if the object contains any arrays, i'd also like to see what's in them, and for all those objects inside i would also like to be able to go deeper into those objects.

The reason i'm asking this, is that I can't debug my code locally (because it uses a web-service that will only run on the production), and I can't install Visual Studio on the production server, So i need to be able to actually debug on the production server. I can write my code locally though, and upload it to the production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what Oded said but its kinda dangerous because its exposing the internal workings of your application via a Web Page call.

If I were in your shoes the first thing I would do is figure out a way to get out of your [Developmestuction environment](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Developmestuction_Environment.aspx)

You can also try remote debugging as Paddy wrote but this can freeze up the environment for other users when your hit pause or hit a break point. (all threads freeze even the ones that aren't "yours")

Instead I would either add logging to the application or use [debug diag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en#SystemRequirements) to take snapshots and then inspect them via [WinDBG](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892277). Note there is a steep learning curve for WinDBG

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in.

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) to build up the list of members for an object (and query the values), and use that to build up HTML.

Comment: Oded: I'm using ComponentModel right now, which is actualy an easyer interface for Reflection. I know how i should create the code to view an entire object in HTML, but it will be a lot of work, so i wondered if nobody has done this before

Comment: @Jules - of course it is hard, and not widely required (what with remote debugging) that's why it's not been done yet, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at remote debugging:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Paddy: That looks useful, but because of security reasons (people in my company are a bit too paranoid sometimes) i don't think we can install this on the server

Comment: @Jules - That is often the case, and this is not an ideal solution, as mentioned below, it can disrupt other users.  Conrad's advice is best - you should try to find a way to run this locally, the inability to do so will only cause you difficulties in the long term.

Comment: and in the short term, i can assure you ;)

Comment: @Jules - can you give us a little more information as to why this won't run locally - we may be able to advise a solution?